# Slick: How can I query rows that match a Map's key and that key's value?

Tags: scala, slick

I want a query that matches a row if, given a parameter `foo: Map[A,B]`, `row.a.inSet(foo.keySet) && row.b == foo(row.a)`. The example

```
class UserTable extends Table[Foo] {
    id: Long
    first: String
    last: String
}


def getFoosMatchingMap(lastByFirst: Map[String, String]): Seq[Foo] = {
    rows.filter(r => r.first.inSet(lastByFirst.keySet) && r.last ==
lastByFirst(r.first)).list
}
```

which doesn't compile since `r.first` is a `Column[String]`. Is there a simple way to generate this query that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out

```
  def findBy(m: Map[String, String]) =
    TableQuery[UserTable].filter { row =>
      val criteria = m.map {
        case (column, value) =>
          row.column[String](column) === value
      }.reduceLeftOption(_ && _).get
    }.to[List]
```